# Why is pandas data frame returning everything as a string?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types

I have a pandas data frame read from a csv. It has mixed data types, strings and floats (can be integers; it doesn't matter which for my data processing).

When I am trying to access the rows of integers, however, I am getting a string return rather than a list of floats. Even the '[' at the ends are counted as strings!

I am trying to read my data in the most efficient way possible. My specific task is to run through the list of transcription factors (should be a list of strings in row 3) for each tissue (entries along the top horizontal row), to perform an API call with this string. I also ned to subtract the corresponding value in the list of floats or integers in row 2 from row 1. At the moment, I have been trying to convert the string to the list I need, but there must be a more efficient way to do this.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import json

drug = 'ACETAMINOPHEN'
tissue = 'aorta'
df = pd.read_csv(r'expression/%s/tt.csv' %(drug), sep=',')
tissue_TFs = df['Tissue: %s' %tissue][2]
a = df['Tissue: %s' %tissue][0][1:-1]
b = df['Tissue: %s' %tissue][1][1:-1]
activations = [float(s) for s in a.split(',')]
inhibitions = [float(s) for s in b.split(',')]

net_weight = [(activations[i] - inhibitions[i]) for i in range(len(tissue_TFs)-2)]
'''
no_target_data = []
genes_list = []

for i, TF in enumerate(tissue_TFs):
    try:
        response = requests.get("https://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/Harmonizome/api/1.0/gene_set/%s/TRANSFAC+Curated+Transcription+Factor+Targets" %TF)
        data = response.json()
        target_genes = [gene['symbol'] for key, gene in data['associations'].items()]
        print(target_genes)
    except:
        no_target_data = no_target_data + [TF]

'''
```

Data: tt.csv on [this github page](https://github.com/joanna-lada/gene_data)

Comment: pandas only return the data type as what the input is. If you input an int, it will return an int.

Comment: The csv file has quotes around the number lists, i.e. `"[0.0, 4.0, 7.0, 9.0, ...]"`.  If it's quoted, it's a string.

Comment: @JohnGordon It doesn't look this way when I open tt.csv from the github pge! Do you know the resolution? I made the file myself, so I can edit it to the right format.

Comment: If you click "Raw" in the upper right corner to display the file as-is with no extra formatting, you'll see the quotes.

Comment: @JohnGordon !! It is true! Thank you. Will try to find the issue at source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution facilitating easier access to your data.

For demonstration purpose, I took a fragment of your source file
(title and just 2 columns, with limited length of included lists):

```
Title,Tissue: area 24,Tissue: area 9
Activation path,"[0.0, 4.0, 7.0]","[0.0, 4.0, 7.0]"
Inhibition path,"[2.0, 3.0, 1.0]","[2.0, 3.0, 1.0]"
Transcription factors,"['P19793', 'P04150', 'Q16665', 'P40763']","['P19793', 'P04150', 'Q16665', 'P40763']"
Undetermined effect,"[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]","[0.0, 1.0, 1.0]"
```

To covert strings like `[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]` to true list, I defined
a converter function:

```
def strToList(src):
    return re.split(', ?', src[1:-1])
```

It drops initial and terminal brackets and splits the inner part,
getting just a list of strings.

Then I read the CSV file, applying this converter to all columns except
the initial one:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Tissues.csv', converters={1: strToList, 2: strToList})
```

Reading the real input file (with all "list" columns), you will have to
extend *converters* to include also further columns.

The result is:

```
                   Title                           Tissue: area 24                            Tissue: area 9
0        Activation path                           [0.0, 4.0, 7.0]                           [0.0, 4.0, 7.0]
1        Inhibition path                           [2.0, 3.0, 1.0]                           [2.0, 3.0, 1.0]
2  Transcription factors  ['P19793', 'P04150', 'Q16665', 'P40763']  ['P19793', 'P04150', 'Q16665', 'P40763']
3    Undetermined effect                           [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]                           [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Then the first conversion step - change the *df* into a *Series*,
with a MultiIndex (Column name / Title):

```
xx = df.set_index('Title').unstack()
```

The result is:

```
                 Title                
Tissue: area 24  Activation path                                   [0.0, 4.0, 7.0]
                 Inhibition path                                   [2.0, 3.0, 1.0]
                 Transcription factors    ['P19793', 'P04150', 'Q16665', 'P40763']
                 Undetermined effect                               [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
Tissue: area 9   Activation path                                   [0.0, 4.0, 7.0]
                 Inhibition path                                   [2.0, 3.0, 1.0]
                 Transcription factors    ['P19793', 'P04150', 'Q16665', 'P40763']
                 Undetermined effect                               [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
dtype: object
```

For now we still have each source list "as is", but we want to convert
each such list into a sequence of rows. To do it, run:

```
data = xx.apply(pd.Series).stack()
```

The result is:

```
                 Title                   
Tissue: area 24  Activation path        0         0.0
                                        1         4.0
                                        2         7.0
                 Inhibition path        0         2.0
                                        1         3.0
                                        2         1.0
                 Transcription factors  0    'P19793'
                                        1    'P04150'
                                        2    'Q16665'
                                        3    'P40763'
                 Undetermined effect    0         0.0
                                        1         0.0
                                        2         1.0
Tissue: area 9   Activation path        0         0.0
                                        1         4.0
                                        2         7.0
                 Inhibition path        0         2.0
                                        1         3.0
                                        2         1.0
                 Transcription factors  0    'P19793'
                                        1    'P04150'
                                        2    'Q16665'
                                        3    'P40763'
                 Undetermined effect    0         0.0
                                        1         1.0
                                        2         1.0
dtype: object
```

And finally, to remove initial and trailing apostrohpes, present in
*Transcription factors*, run:

```
data = data.str.replace(r"^'|'$", '')
```

**Conversion to floats**

You can not convert the **whole** result to floats, because
*Transcription factors* are not convertible to numbers.
Instead you can run a "partial conversion", limited to data from
other source rows:

```
data2 = pd.to_numeric(data[data.index.get_level_values(1) !=
    'Transcription factors'])
```

**How to use the above *data*:**

E.g. if you want to compute `net_weight` for some column from your
CSV file, run:

```
net_weight = data2[('Tissue: area 24', 'Activation path')]\
    - data2[('Tissue: area 24', 'Inhibition path')]
```

Comment: Wonderfully clear answer step by step! Thank you very much!